# Can a prepared statement hold multiple queries in php

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to protect my queries from SQL injections, recently. I have started turning the strings I used to make the queries into statements, however, some of the strings I made need to make multiple queries simultaneously, because one insert's id will be added to the next one as a foreign key, which I'll get by using the LAST_INSERT_ID(), and I need them to be executed one after another because of it.

Can a statement hold multiple queries simultaneously and be executed at once?

Here's what the code was before, by the by.

````
$sql = "INSERT INTO `user_info`(`first_name`, `last_name`, `phone`, `cpf`) 
            VALUES ('{$firstName}', '{$lastName}', '{$phone}', '{$cpf}');";
$sql .= "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @mysql_variable_here;";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO `{$table}`(`email`, `password`, `active`,`user_info_id`, `created`, `role_id`" . $restaurantInsert . ")
            VALUES ('{$email}','{$password}', 1, @mysql_variable_here, '{$created}', {$role}" . $restaurantValue . " );"; 
$sql .= "INSERT INTO `address`(number, street, city, state, zip, district, country, created, user_info_id)
            VALUES ('{$number}', '{$street}', '{$city}', '{$stateCode}', '{$zip}', '{$district}', 'BR', '{$created}', @mysql_variable_here);";

$result = $conn->multi_query($sql);```
````

Comment: This is not secure. No usage of `multi_query` is secure. Use parameterized queries with prepared statements, and transactions.

Comment: What is in `$restaurantInsert` and `$restaurantValue`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't execute multiple statements in a [prepared query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html):

> SQL syntax for prepared statements does not support multi-statements
>   (that is, multiple statements within a single string separated by ;
>   characters)

so you will need to prepare and execute each of the queries separately, using `mysqli_stmt::insert_id` to get the appropriate `id` value for the second and third queries:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `user_info`(`first_name`, `last_name`, `phone`, `cpf`) 
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $firstName, $lastName, $phone, $cpf);
$stmt->execute();
$insert_id = $stmt->insert_id;
$stmt->close();

$sql = "INSERT INTO `{$table}`(`email`, `password`, `active`,`user_info_id`, `created`, `role_id`" . $restaurantInsert . ")
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('ssiisss', $email, $password, 1, $insert_id, $created, $role, $restaurantValue);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

$sql = "INSERT INTO `address`(number, street, city, state, zip, district, country, created, user_info_id)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$country = 'BR';
$stmt->bind_param('sssssssi', $number, $street, $city, $stateCode, $zip, $district, $country, $created, $insert_id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Note I'm not 100% certain what you're trying to achieve with `role_id" . $restaurantInsert . "`, you might need to edit the second query appropriately to use that.